# Failing to plot the frequency distribution of a table

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I apologize if my question seems silly but I am relatively junior.

I am trying to plot the frequency distribution of value counts for a column containing categorical variables.

I am using the value_counts() and calling the plot() method and specifying the bar kind, but instead of a bar plot something weird gets plotted.

here is my code:

```
df['AC Type'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

Here is a screenshot of what actually gets plotted. I really don't understand. I tried to create
a variable containing the value counts for the column but it doesn't change the result.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW8p7.png)

Thanks in advance

Luca

Comment: it seems there are too many categories to show. how many different categories are in the column, if you do `df['AC Type'].unique().size`

Comment: a good few hundreds. the values range from 1 to 33. I am trying to exclude values below 2 to make it fit in a bar plot but haven't managed. I would still like to plot all values above that threshold. Should I bin it or plot separate charts? 
by the way thanks for replying

Comment: yeah, to filter out the value, try `df = df[df['AC Type']  > 2]`, if you still have more than a dozens of different values, maybe it is a good idea to bin them

Comment: it worked, even though I had to increase the threshold, I was probably too optmistic and didn't  even consider how messy the chart would look. I appreciate the reply, thanks a lot!